# Openfire not storing offline messages

Tags: php, mysql, openfire

Goal :- Store Offline Messages.

I am not able to store offline message.

I have installed monitoring service plugin which used to store messages into server.

[image]

Normal messages are stored in **ofMessageArchive** table and for offline messages there is table named **ofOffline**.

Even i have checked offline message settings under Server --> server settings

[image]

There i have selected Always store message option.

I have tried

**1)** Reload Monitoring service plugin.

**2)** Restart Openfire server.

Still offline messages are stored into **ofMessageArchive** though user is offline and not stored in **ofOffline** table.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Are you facing this issue with one-one chat or with group chat?

Comment: Hi @ShoaibAhmadGondal can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631928/getting-all-group-messages-back-when-connecting-to-xmpp-from-ios-and-android-end

Comment: Yes i have replied there.

Comment: Yes let's discuss there!

Answer (score 0):

For user's offline message openfire store message in ofOffline.openfire provide settings for offline message 
**server->server settings->offline messages**

[image]

It is only for user to user chat but for group chat you can use ofMessageArchive plugin it store both user's and group chat history.if user is offline or online.