# Getting All group messages back when connecting to xmpp from ios and android end

Tags: android, ios, openfire

I am using **openfire version 4.0.1**

Using openfire [Rest Api](https://github.com/gidkom/php-openfire-restapi) i have created group chat rooms in the service servicename.xx.xx.xxx.xxx.

Now rooms are created what is happening , once user connect to the xmpp server all the group messages are receiving back to that user which makes application stuck.

I heared about Group Chat History Settings under group chat settings.

[image]

I have truncate all the group messages which is stored in **ofMessageArchive** table of openfire.

Still, when user connects to the xmpp that user will receive all the messages of all the group which he is member with even though i have cleared all the messages from ofMessageArchive table.

How to prevent those messages which are comming through xmpp?

Any Help would appriciate.

Comment: Anyone experiencing same kind of issue ?

Comment: Yes i have experienced the issue, can you share the presence packet which you are sending to join room?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal

i am creating a room from ios end and create room object of xmpp and then activating room to my connected xmpp stream than after i am  sending presence to stream (Presence type ="available")

Comment: here is an example packet which contains history tag...so i want to look at the presence packet which is being sent from your side. kindly log the packet and share.

<presence
    from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    id='n13mt3l'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'>
    <history maxchars='65000'/>
  </x>
</presence>

Comment: Actully i am not sending packet from web-end to ios end we have used one plugin named Monitoring Service this plugin inserts packets (messages) to my server which stores from,to and body.

Those messages are coming from xmpp server to directly ios end when user connects the xmpp server.

Comment: "maxchars" or "maxstanzas" or "seconds" property of the room joining packet,this property is defining number of messages or seconds(in duration) which is messages limit.Accordingly that messages limit,messages are retrieve when user connected to room.
for example  maxchars = 2
then room stream return last 2 messages after successful connection to room.

Comment: Group chat conversations are also saved in ofMucConversationLog. Can you check your openfire database and see if this table contains the chat which you are getting back.

Comment: I have also cleared ofMucConversationLog table still all messages are received from server when user connects to xmpp server from ios and android end.

Comment: @downvoter please comment out your concern when you do downvote to the question  / Answer thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your Openfire version.

However, for Openfire 4.0.2

Groupchat history it's based on many params on database and some on client.
Behaviour it's not ever linear.

1) in table `OFPROPERTY` the property `xmpp.muc.history.reload.limit`  (this works in days, for example put 30 means "last 30 days")

2) in table `OFMUCSERVICEPROP`, for each serviceid, you can have (or not) 0+ values. For example, for serviceid 1 (`conference`), without params you'll get last 25 messages, or you can set by db or programmatically name `history.type` and type (`all` to get all the history, `none` for your case)

3) **With smack API** You can send a DiscussionHistory request while joining chat: with this object you can set to 0 all the parameters (like: number of stanzas and so on).

`history.type` it's the top level one to set: just declare it as `none` and no history will be retrived.

Comment: I am using openfire version 4.0.1 as you suggested i have changed history.type to none from all in OFMUCSERVICEPROP table and checked from ios end still i am getting all the messages of groups which i am member with from start to end. Another option you've given is xmpp.muc.history.reload.limit but i am not able to find any property named xmpp.muc.history.reload.limit. even i've tried to insert a new row with xmpp.muc.history.reload.limit and set that value to 0 still same issue i am facing from ios end.

Comment: Ok, so you probably have a default in subscription request where you subscribe for history. I did not mentioned that because probably you already had a check about, but if you use the API rest maybe you are not checking in detail subscribe params; by the way, if you disable "log conversation" in Room Options (Groupchat menu -> select service -> select Room) in theory will be not possible to retrive any history

Comment: you're talking about default in subscription request from ios end ? & yes i am using rest api all the operation (add/remove) members from room, this functionality is done from web-end. I saw room settings there i have already disabled Log Room Conversations at the time of room creation(dynamically). roomsettings ( http://prnt.sc/d8sfps ) default room settings ( http://prnt.sc/d8sg6u )

Comment: Ok, did you resetted caches? Maybe they comes from caches or there's somthing really strange...

Comment: Yes I have tried to clear cache ( http://prnt.sc/d9ua6i ) Is there any other way from there i can clear cache and stop receiving all group messages?

Comment: i forgot to mention that in most cases you need to stop&start Openfire to get values updated. history.type must works after a restart, honestly I have no idea if there will be any plugin that acts like a workaround for this